# oracle SQL left join() or full out join () exclude records based on keys

Tags: sql, oracle, set, left-join, full-outer-join

I want to exclude the records in one table if it appear in the other table (based on keys)

I want to delete the record in the first table:
cust_recommendataion 
which has the same( cust_id and product_id) in the second table 
the distinct pair of ( cust_id and product_id) in the second table may only a subset of the first table' distinct pair of ( cust_id and product_id)
also there are some '( cust_id and product_id)' pair in the second table may unique.

I have 2 tables 
1.  cust_recommendataion: for each cust_id has multiple product_id s

---

cust_id | product_id | rank

---

2. cust_last_buy    ; for each cust_id has multiple product_id

---

cust_id | product_id | date

---

would love to know the suggestion how to do that. by using left join()or full out join()or any other suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: thank you, I know how to use R to create the dataset but do not know how to use SQL creating original data set. Will try

Comment: It's not clear what you want to delete. Maybe, you want to delete rows in cust_recommendataion that also appear in the cust_last_buy?

Comment: @luca.vercelli Yes. that is what i want.

Comment: In that case, rad's answer is the correct one. Oracle does not suport DELETE/JOIN clauses, AFAIK. Other databases (such as Teradata and MySQL) support them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution using `Exist`:

```
Delete from cust_recommendataion c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
           *
        FROM
            cust_last_buy
        WHERE
            cust_id = c.cust_id
             and 
            product_id = c.product_id
    )
```

Comment: Hi rad,if i want to detect those line first before delete. Could I use left join?

Comment: If you want to see what records it's going to `delete`, you can replace the `delete` word with `select *`. If that's what you meant.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the input!